# Add subfolder to pytest tmpdir_factory without appending a numeral

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

In `python 3.11` using `pytest`, I want to add a subdirectory called `trial` to a temporary folder without appending a numeral to the subdirectory name. If I try

```
tmpdir_factory.mktemp('trial')
```

I get a directory with a path like `temporary_directory_path/trial0` whereas I want to have `temporary_directory_path/trial`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `numbered` parameter to `False`

```
tmpdir_factory.mktemp('trial', numbered=False)
```